# How to get nᵗʰ highest value using plain SQL

Tags: sql

What is the simplest way to get the n<sup>th</sup> highest value from a result set using plain SQL?

The result set would be huge, thus need to consider performance too.

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 3):

This is the T-SQL (SQL-Server 2005 and greater) approach using [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx):

```
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT 
      Col1, Col2, ValueCol,
      RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ValueCol DESC) -- change to ASC if you want lowest first
   FROM 
      dbo.TableName
)
SELECT 
   Col1, Col2, ValueCol
FROM 
   CTE
WHERE 
   RN = @nthhighestvalue
```

If you want all rows with the same value use [`DENSE RANK`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx) instead.

[**Difference between ROW_NUMBER, RANK and DENSE_RANK**](http://mangalpardeshi.blogspot.de/2008/10/difference-between-rownumber-rank-and.html)

Comment: isn't it possible there will be X `nthHighestValue`s that match a specific RN (depending on how it gets partitioned)?

Comment: Well no that isn't what is desired.  My experience is with Oracle, so I may be off base, but the row_number() function has to be partitioned against something.  It is that something that can cause X RNs being the same (per partition).  Further does SQL Server order by DESC by default?

Comment: @Woot4Moo: Default is `ASC` and `OVER` needs no `PARTITION BY`. If `PARTITION BY` is not specified, the function treats all rows of the query result set as a single group. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx

Comment: I envy the SQL server users :)

Comment: @Woot4Moo: However, edited the answer since you might be right and he wants the nth **highest** value, so i've changed to `ORDER BY ValueCol DESC`.

Comment: @Woot4Moo: Neither Oracle requires the "partition by".

Answer (score 3):

[This article](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/database-sql/find-nth-highest-salary-sql/) talks about this question in depth, and I will quote code from it below:

**Solution 1:** This SQL to find the Nth highest salary should work in SQL Server, MySQL, DB2, Oracle, Teradata, and almost any other RDBMS: (note: low performance because of subquery)

```
SELECT * /*This is the outer query part */
FROM Employee Emp1
WHERE (N-1) = ( /* Subquery starts here */
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(Emp2.Salary))
FROM Employee Emp2
WHERE Emp2.Salary > Emp1.Salary)
```

The most important thing to understand in the query above is that the subquery is evaluated each and every time a row is processed by the outer query. In other words, the inner query can not be processed independently of the outer query since the inner query uses the Emp1 value as well.

In order to find the Nth highest salary, we just find the salary that has exactly N-1 salaries greater than itself.

---

**Solution 2:** Find the nth highest salary using the TOP keyword in SQL Server

```
SELECT TOP 1 Salary
FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT TOP N Salary
      FROM Employee
      ORDER BY Salary DESC
      ) AS Emp
ORDER BY Salary
```

---

**Solution 3:** Find the nth highest salary in SQL Server without using TOP

```
SELECT Salary FROM Employee 
ORDER BY Salary DESC OFFSET N-1 ROW(S) 
FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
```

Note that I haven’t personally tested the SQL above, and I believe that it will only work in SQL Server 2012 and up.

---

**Solution 4:** Works in MySQL

```
SELECT Salary FROM Employee 
ORDER BY Salary DESC LIMIT n-1,1
```

The LIMIT clause takes two arguments in that query – the first argument specifies the offset of the first row to return, and the second specifies the maximum number of rows to return.

---

**Solution 5:** Works in Oracle

```
select * from (
  select Emp.*, 
row_number() over (order by Salary DESC) rownumb 
from Employee Emp
)
where rownumb = n;  /*n is nth highest salary*/
```

---

**Solution 6:** Works in Oracle way 2

```
select * FROM (
select EmployeeID, Salary
,rank() over (order by Salary DESC) ranking
from Employee
)
WHERE ranking = N;
```

Answer (score 0):

Start by producing an ordered, numbered dataset and then select from that.  The precise syntax depends on the RDBMS but, for example, in Oracle you can do

```
SELECT ROWNUM, SOMEVAL
FROM (SELECT SOMEVAL FROM SOMETABLE ORDER BY SOMEVAL DESC)
```

Given the above set you can

```
SELECT SOMEVAL WHERE ROWNUM = :N
```

Comment: no you cannot.  In Oracle ROWNUM != row_number() analytic function.

Comment: Have you ever used Oracle's analytic functions?  You have a fundamental misunderstanding of how the database stores data and as such should not offer advice that is grossly incorrect.  I highly recommend you do some research on the topic of database row storage.  Further giving a general answer that doesn't apply in the majority of cases is even more infuriating.

Comment: I have used the analytic functions, yes, and I have a good understanding of relational databases and physical storage but neither issue is relevant in this case. I believe my answer is sound.

Answer (score 0):

In a general database, you can do this with a subquery and two `order by`s.  The problem is that top/limit/rownum syntax is not standard.  In some databases you would write:

Comment: Ignore this incomplete answer.  I am having trouble uploading answers.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT col1, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY col1) rnum_col1 FROM table1
) WHERE rnum_col1 = 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to find the 5th highest salary, you first take the first 5 distinct salary order by descending order so that the last one is the 5th highest salary (See inner query). You then reorder it in ascending order and take the first.

```
SELECT TOP 1 Salary FROM
(
  SELECT DISTINCT TOP 5 Salary
  FROM Employee
  ORDER BY Salary DESC)  t

ORDER BY  Salary ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Sub Query will list out top 'n' highest salary values. From that list minimum value will be the nth highest salary.

```
`SELECT min(salary) FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT TOP n salary FROM EmployeeTable ORDER BY salary desc);`
```

Eg :- SQL query to find third maximum salary

```
`SELECT min(salary) FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT TOP 3 salary FROM EmployeeTable ORDER BY salary desc);`
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to incur the overhead of sorting, and in my example `rownum` is the sorted row number, not the physical location.

Since everyone is using analytic functions to show how this works here is one:

```
   select foo,bar, max(baz)  
    from  
    (
       select *   
      from  
      (  
          select foo,bar,baz, row_number() over 
          (partition by some_identifier_that_Groups order by  value DESC) rn 
      )    
       where rn = 1  -- get the highest value for each partition    
    ) group by foo,bar
```

Comment: if this is Oracle it will not work because the rownum gets allocated BEFORE the sort.

Comment: You have completely changed your answer, which is fine, but I am not sure it suits the OPs 'Plain Sql' requirement.

Comment: @HughJones and yet you use an analytic function, which in turn makes your answer just as "invalid" as well as every other person that answered OP's question.

Comment: actually it doesnt work - you have to sort the dataset BEFORE you allocate the ROWNUM.  It is possible that the very recent Oracle versions are different but I doubt it.

Comment: @HughJones mistyped, your solution NEEDS an analytic function to be correct.

Comment: @HughJones ROWNUM is not the same as the row_number() ANALYTIC FUNCTION.  They are TWO very DIFFERENT concepts.

Comment: @HughJones here is the link: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm

Comment: I dont believe I used a single function in my answer.  I accept that ROWNUM is not 'Plain Sql', so you have me there.

Comment: I am perfectly aware they are two completely different concepts.  My approach makes no reference to analytic functions - that was your suggestion from the outset.