# How to write an SQL statement to return the second largest applicationid

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

I'm trying to write an SQL statement to return the second largest applicationid anyone got any idea of how to do this?

This was a question ask of me so I do not have any code to start, I was thinking that SQL has a built in method to do this.

Comment: Seveveral answers to this already exist: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32100/what-is-the-simplest-sql-query-to-find-the-second-largest-value is one ... or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80706/query-to-find-nth-max-value-of-a-column or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14196427/how-to-get-nth-highest-value-using-plain-sql.  each has it's own merit based on version of SQL-server and use cases.  couldn't second become nth?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SQL Server 2012 and `ApplicationId` is unique in the table being queried:

```
select ApplicationId
from Applications
order by ApplicationId desc
offset 1 fetch first 1 row only;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`rank`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx) window function:

```
SELECT applicationid
FROM   (SELECT applicationid,
               DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY applicationid DESC) AS rk
        FROM   mytable)
WHERE  rk = 2
```

Comment: Id `applicationid` is not unique there might be no rank 2 (e.g. 1-1-3), you better use `DENSE_RANK` instead

Answer (score 0):

```
select ApplicationId
from Applications a1 where 3=(select count(ApplicationId)
from Applications a2 where a2.ApplicationId>a1.ApplicationId)
```