# How does this query perform in the query optimizer?

Tags: mysql, sql

Solving this question https://leetcode.com/problems/nth-highest-salary/ and found this solution (but no description of what/how this query performs..)

```
CREATE FUNCTION getNthHighestSalary(N INT) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
SET N = N - 1;
  RETURN (
      # Write your MySQL query statement below.
      select distinct(salary) from employee order by salary desc LIMIT 1 OFFSET N
  );
END
```

What does `SET N = N - 1;` mean and why does deleting `LIMIT 1` slows down performance?
Is there a better way of writing this? What about `row_number()` or `rank()`?

Comment: Note that DISTINCT is not a function

Answer (score 2):

> What does SET N = N - 1; mean?

If you search for second highest salary then you need to set offset to 1.

```
N = 2-1
N = 1
```

Main query:

```
select distinct(salary) from employee order by salary desc LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c17cd7de490565572166b90deda340be)**

MySQL does not allow to use expression so this code is invalid:

```
select distinct(salary) from employee order by salary desc LIMIT 1 OFFSET N-1
```

---

> Is there a better way of writing this?

Yes, this query could be rewritten at least in few different ways. You need to define "better" - better perfromance/readability/...

[How to get nth highest value using plain SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14196427/how-to-get-nth-highest-value-using-plain-sql)

---

> What about row_number() or rank()?

MySQL 8.0 supports windowed functions. So yes, they should be considered as options.

Answer (score 0):

Although there are other ways to write the query, I would expect your version:

```
select distinct salary
from employee
order by salary desc 
limit 1 offset n;
```

To work optimally with an index on `employee(salary desc)`.

In general, window functions assign a value to *every* row before filtering -- even when they are using an index.  With an index `order by`/`limit` should simply stop at the desired row, so that is faster.

I'm pretty sure that MySQL is still smart enough to use an index with the `select distinct`.  If it actually requires sorting, then window functions might have a similar performance.